# Comparing two sql timpestamps in android

Tags: android, timestamp, compare

I have used `compareTo()` method of `java.sql.Timestamp` for timestamp comparosion as shown in code below. But it is not working properly.

How to compare two timestamps in android?

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class t {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timestamp startTime  = new Timestamp(2011,7,10,10,43,00,00);
    Timestamp endTime = new Timestamp(2011,9,13,10,5,00,00);
    Timestamp currentTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    if((startTime.compareTo(currentTime))< 0){
        System.out.println("late start");
    }
    else{            
    if((currentTime.compareTo(endTime))<0){
            System.out.println("Current time inbetween");
     }
     else{
            System.out.println("current time is greater than end time");
        }
    }        
}}
```

Comment: Why you are doing `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya The output of comparison given by program is not correct as expected. For above program it shows "Current time inbetween" when the expected output is "current time is greater than end time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method TimeStamp what you have used in your code is deprecated

```
Timestamp startTime  = new Timestamp(2011,7,10,10,43,00,00);
```

This will return below output (Not sure why)

```
3911-08-10 10:43:00.0
```

use below code for android to compare timestamp

```
public void checkDate() {
        Timestamp startTime  = new Timestamp(getDateMillies(2011,7,10,10,43,0));
        Timestamp endTime = new Timestamp(getDateMillies(2011, 9, 13, 10, 5, 0));
        Timestamp currentTime = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        if((startTime.compareTo(currentTime))< 0){
            System.out.println("late start");
        }
        else{
            if((currentTime.compareTo(endTime))<0){
                System.out.println("Current time inbetween");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("current time is greater than end time");
            }
        }
    }
```

Below code is an implementation for getDateMillies()

```
private long getDateMillies(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);

    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) returns -1 if lhs is less than rhs.

If I understand correctly, I think your code should be

```
// If start time is after current time
if((startTime.compareTo(currentTime)) > 0){
    System.out.println("late start");
}
else {
    if((currentTime.compareTo(endTime))<0){
        System.out.println("Current time inbetween");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("current time is greater than end time");
    }
}
```

Also, as janki pointed out, current time should be instantiated as

```
 Timestamp currentTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

without the division by 1000

Answer (score 0):

Check this

Pass your dates to method

```
public static int isValidDate(String start,String end){
        int valid=0;
        DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        Date d3 = null;
        Calendar curDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dfcurDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        String datecurrent = dfcurDate.format(curDate.getTime());
        try {
            d1 = formatter1.parse(datecurrent);
            d2 = new Date(Long.parseLong(end));
            d3 = new Date(Long.parseLong(start));
            System.out.println(d1.after(d3) && d1.before(d2));
            if (d1.after(d3) && d1.before(d2)) {
                valid=1;
            } else if (d1.before(d2)) {
                valid=2;
            } } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

if return 1--Current 2-- future time